# Google Spreadsheet - select worksheet with JSONP

Tags: jquery, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

## First endpoint

I am reading [Google query language specification](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#Setting_the_Query_in_the_Data_Source_URL). This endpoint allows me to query data but I have not figured out how to select page, how can I select page? I tried:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  url: 'http://spreadsheets.google.com/a/google.com/tq?key=ABCDE&tq=select%mypage!A'
})
```

Note the `mypage!`. But this does not work.

Also, when trying without `mypage!`, I receive an answer like this:

```
// Data table response
google.visualization.Query.setResponse({"version":"0.6...
```

Where should I read about this response? do I need to load some Google Library? why, if I just want the data? is there a better approach to get just data?

## Second endpoint

I also read this [example](https://developers.google.com/gdata/samples/spreadsheet_sample). This allows to select worksheet with a code `od6`, `od7` and so on, why it starts in `od6`?, is just my document? where I can find documentation about this.

For both endpoints I am using JSONP.

Comment: I don't see any documentation on it, but adding gid as a url parameter selects a specific sheet. The sheets are numbered in order of creation, not in the order that they appear at the bottom. `http://spreadsheets.google.com/a/google.com/tq?key=ABCDE&gid=6`

Comment: `gid` works in the hash part of the url, to put it in query part did not work for me...

Comment: You can get spreadsheet data as CSV, or use the google-spreadsheet-api (gdata API). or even google-apps-script. But if you need the SQL like data processing, then I suspect this is your best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **gid=** e.g :

https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=0Ao_WaOWBqWmjdGRZV3dxdW1sdXhaeUs0cko5ZEVldEE&gid=0&tq=select%20A

I read that #gid and od6 are not connected, and the only way to get the od6 that links to the #gid, is to loop through all the #gid values to find the matching sheet.

I suspect there is no way to add "gid" into the query string, as there is no way to merge data from more than one source with the query, or none that I have seen.

Answer (score 0):

To use a gid did not work for me, I used:

```
http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/MY_KEY/public/basic?alt=json-in-script
```

To get a list of worksheets and then with the response, I searched in it the title of my spreadsheet and get the id which is `od6`, `od4`, etc.