# Select worksheet Google Visualization API Query Language

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am reading [this](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage).

Is there a way I can select worksheet there, I need to do queries in a specific worksheet.

I [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20361667/google-spreadsheet-select-worksheet-with-jsonp/20385409#20385409) with Google Spreadsheet API, but answer I am getting is difficult to parse, since fields are calculated by Google and there is no documentation about them.

## Workaround

I just moved sheet to the first position and it worked with a query like the one specified in [the first link I posted](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage).

Note the first sheet is selected by default and there is no way to select sheet, that, is my question.

Comment: Hi, my link the one you pasted, is from Google Spreadsheet API, I am wondering about Google Visualization API Query Language. Thanks, I changed the title.

Comment: See the word tried in my post? it has a link there, they are the same. It has all to do with Google Spreadsheet API, maybe you pasted the wrong link. Google Query Language URLs start with http://spreadsheets.google.com/a/google.com/tq.

Comment: Hope you are just having an off week, and will be back to normal soon.  Kevin and myself did describe to you how to do this, and the solution works. I posted the answer, again, below, please try it this time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easier than trying luck with a `gid` number there is the possibilty to pass `sheet` parameter with sheet name:

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=0AsD4widwbn0rdE9HM2VwZ1h2UktFUi0xTy1lOVlqblE&sheet=sheet1&tq=select%20A
https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=0AsD4widwbn0rdE9HM2VwZ1h2UktFUi0xTy1lOVlqblE&sheet=sheet2&tq=select%20A
```

Note the sheet parameter. I could not find source of this again.

Comment: Cool, looks very handy. Please post if you find a source.

Comment: Google documentation is usually hard to work with, but they really do amazing things.

Comment: **Docs** for extra parameters: headers, sheet, gid -  https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets#Google_Spreadsheets_as_a_Data_Source

Comment: It maybe useful to add `tqx=out:html` parameter  to end of query string when you debugging and playing with the query from the browser, this way you can see result in html. eg. Query from above for Sheet1 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YnBi5feUqHj1vOrI5Xj70h1UMeRceRKbwbVSBdCc0Eg/gviz/tq?sheet=sheet1&tq=select+A&tqx=out:html  or queyr for Sheet2 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YnBi5feUqHj1vOrI5Xj70h1UMeRceRKbwbVSBdCc0Eg/gviz/tq?sheet=sheet2&tq=select+A&tqx=out:html

Comment: Also there's gotcha: when sheet name is invalid - it will default to first sheet without throwing any erorrs. eg https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YnBi5feUqHj1vOrI5Xj70h1UMeRceRKbwbVSBdCc0Eg/gviz/tq?sheet=SHEET_THAT_DOESNT_EXIST&tq=select+A&tqx=out:html

Answer (score 1):

Use **gid=**

like this:

https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=0Ao_WaOWBqWmjdGRZV3dxdW1sdXhaeUs0cko5ZEVldEE&gid=0&tq=select%20A

https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=0Ao_WaOWBqWmjdGRZV3dxdW1sdXhaeUs0cko5ZEVldEE&gid=4&tq=select%20A

Notice that the gid is not the same, and the result is not the same.

Note: gid values start at 0, so sheet1: gid=0, sheet2: gid=1. The gid values never change even if a sheet is deleted/renamed.

Comment: I know and understand perfectly what you mean.
I just created a spreadsheet with 2 worksheets, is public to the web: https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=0AsD4widwbn0rdE9HM2VwZ1h2UktFUi0xTy1lOVlqblE&gid=2&tq=select%20A.
Note how changing gid param does not change the content in response.
Document content can be seen here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AsD4widwbn0rdE9HM2VwZ1h2UktFUi0xTy1lOVlqblE#gid=1.
Thanks.

Comment: Note that with `gid=2` response contains `"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"Some"}]},{"c":[{"v":"content"}]` which is  the first page. And when gid is changed, the same content is present.